# Combat Game - C++, Given a Spawner Class, How can I spawn stronger enemy every round

Tags: c++, class

I have a problem in my OOP homework. I have to code a 1 v 1 battle.

This is a Survival Game where in the player fights continuously with enemies until the player dies. The Player gets stronger as he advances through. The enemy also grows stronger every round.

I have created two Classes, The Unit and the Spawner.
We cannot use Inheritance nor Polymorphism.
We Have to use only the simple definition of the class.

My problem is that i cannot think of a SIMPLE way to make the class Spawner spawn a stronger enemy every round.

I have thought of overloading the Unit's Contructor but i have trouble manipulating that.

Would anyone please help?

Here's my Unit Header file (Unit.h):

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

// Class Types
const string CLASS_WARRIOR  = "Warrior" ;
const string CLASS_ASSASSIN = "Assassin";
const string CLASS_MAGE     = "Mage"    ;

// Class Choices
const int CHOICE_WARRIOR    = 1;
const int CHOICE_ASSASSIN   = 2;
const int CHOICE_MAGE       = 3;

// Multipliers
const double MULTIPLIER_DAMAGE  = 0.50f;
const double MULTIPLER_HEAL     = 0.30f;

// Advantage
const bool ADVANTAGE = true;

// Win Bonus
const int BONUS_THREE   = 3;
const int BONUS_FIVE    = 5;

// Minimum and maximum values
const int HIT_RATE_MAX = 80;
const int HIT_RATE_MIN = 20;
const int DAMAGE_MIN = 1;

// Hit or miss
const bool ATTACK_HIT = true;
const bool ATTACK_MISS = false;

class Unit
{
public:
    // Constructors
    Unit(string name, int classChoice);

    // Getters and setters
    string getName();
    string getClass();

    int getHp();
    int getMaxHp();
    int getPower();
    int getVitality();
    int getAgility();
    int getDexterity();

    int getDamage();
    int getHeal();
    int getBonusDamage();
    bool getFirstToAttack();
    bool getHit();

    void setClassStats(const int classChoice);

    // Primary Actions
    void attack(Unit* target);

    // Secondary Actions
    void check(const Unit* target); // Inspects the enemy
    void lvlUp();               // Grants this Unit Bonus Stats on Victory


private:
    // Info
    string mName;
    string mClass;

    // Basic Stats
    int mHp;
    int mMaxHp;
    int mPower;
    int mVitality;
    int mAgility;
    int mDexterity;

    // Derived Stats
    int mDamage;
    int mHitrate;
    int  mHeal;
    int  mBonusDamage;

    // Miscellaneous 
    bool mAdvantage;    // If the player has the advantage
    string mTargetClass;// This Unit keeps in mind the class of this Unit's Opponent for reference
    int mChanceOfHit;   // The random chance if the attack will Hit/Miss
    bool mFirstToAttack;//if this unit will attack first
    bool mHit;          // if the attack is a hit or miss
};
```

Here's my Unit.cpp file (Unit.cpp):

```
#include "Unit.h"


Unit::Unit(string name, int classChoice)
{
    mName = name;

    setClassStats(classChoice);
}

string Unit::getName()
{
    return mName;
}

string Unit::getClass()
{
    return mClass;
}

int Unit::getHp()
{
    return mHp;
}

int Unit::getMaxHp()
{
    return mMaxHp;
}

int Unit::getPower()
{
    return mPower;
}

int Unit::getVitality()
{
    return mVitality;
}

int Unit::getAgility()
{
    return mAgility;
}

int Unit::getDexterity()
{
    return mDexterity;
}

int Unit::getDamage()
{
    return mDamage;
}

int Unit::getHeal()
{
    return mHeal;
}

int Unit::getBonusDamage()
{
    return mBonusDamage;
}

bool Unit::getFirstToAttack()
{
    return mFirstToAttack;
}

bool Unit::getHit()
{
    return mHit;
}

void Unit::setClassStats(const int classChoice)
{
    if (classChoice == CHOICE_WARRIOR) {
        mClass      = CLASS_WARRIOR;
        mMaxHp = 20;
        mHp = mMaxHp;
        mPower      = 15;
        mVitality   = 10;
        mAgility    = 7;
        mDexterity  = 7;

        return;
    }

    else if (classChoice == CHOICE_ASSASSIN) {
        mClass      = CLASS_ASSASSIN;
        mMaxHp = 15;
        mHp         = mMaxHp;
        mPower      = 17;
        mVitality   = 8;
        mAgility    = 12;
        mDexterity  = 10;

        return;
    }

    else if (classChoice == CHOICE_MAGE) {
        mClass      = CLASS_MAGE;
        mMaxHp          = 30;
        mHp = mMaxHp;
        mPower      = 12;
        mVitality   = 12;
        mAgility    = 9;
        mDexterity  = 8;

        return;
    }

    throw exception("Error! Class not part of this game. ");
}

void Unit::attack(Unit * target)
{
    // Determine Whether the attack will Hit/Miss Based on the hit rate
    mChanceOfHit = rrand() % 100 + 1;

    if (mChanceOfHit > mHitrate) {
        mHit = ATTACK_MISS;
        return;
    }


    // Deducts the targets Hp by the Damage given by this Unit (if the attack didn't miss)
    target->mHp -= mDamage;
    mHit = ATTACK_HIT;

    // if target HP is negative, set it to zero
    if (target->mHp < 0) target->mHp = 0;
}

void Unit::check(const Unit * target)
{
    // The Unit Keeps in Mind his target's Class
    if (target->mClass == CLASS_WARRIOR)        mTargetClass = CLASS_WARRIOR;
    else if (target->mClass == CLASS_ASSASSIN)  mTargetClass = CLASS_ASSASSIN;
    else if (target->mClass == CLASS_MAGE)      mTargetClass = CLASS_MAGE;


    // Checks if the Unit is Advantageous Against his Target
    if (mClass == CLASS_WARRIOR) {
        if (target->mClass == CLASS_ASSASSIN) mAdvantage = ADVANTAGE;
        else mAdvantage = false;
    }

    else if (mClass == CLASS_ASSASSIN) {
        if (target->mClass == CLASS_MAGE) mAdvantage = ADVANTAGE;
        else mAdvantage = false;
    }

    else if (mClass == CLASS_MAGE) {
        if (target->mClass == CLASS_WARRIOR) mAdvantage = ADVANTAGE;
        else mAdvantage = false;
    }

    // Determine if this Unit Will Attack first
    if (mAgility >= target->mAgility) mFirstToAttack = true;
    else mFirstToAttack = false;

    // Determines Damage, Bonus Damage ( If Applicable ), and Hit Rate Based on targets stats
    mDamage = mPower - target->mVitality;
    if (mDamage < DAMAGE_MIN) mDamage = DAMAGE_MIN;

    mBonusDamage = mDamage * MULTIPLIER_DAMAGE;

    // Evaluates Damage Based on advantage
    if (mAdvantage) mDamage += mBonusDamage;

    mHitrate = ((float)mDexterity / (float)target->mAgility) * 100;

    //  Clamps the Hit Rate within the Hit Rate Range
    if (mHitrate > HIT_RATE_MAX) mHitrate = HIT_RATE_MAX;
    else if (mHitrate < HIT_RATE_MIN) mHitrate = HIT_RATE_MIN;
}

void Unit::lvlUp()
{
    // Determine Win Bonus Based on the target that he kept in mind
    if (mTargetClass == CLASS_WARRIOR) {
        mMaxHp += BONUS_THREE;
        mVitality += BONUS_THREE;
    }

    else if (mTargetClass == CLASS_ASSASSIN) {
        mAgility += BONUS_THREE;
        mDexterity += BONUS_THREE;
    }

    else if (mTargetClass == CLASS_MAGE) {
        mPower += BONUS_FIVE;
    }

    // Heals the player 30% of his Maximum HP
    mHeal = mMaxHp * MULTIPLER_HEAL;
    mHp += mHeal;
}
```

Here's my Spawner Header file (Spawner.h):

```
 #pragma once

 #include "Unit.h"

 class Spawner
 {
 public:
      Spawner();
      ~Spawner();
       void spawn(Unit*& unit);

  private:
      Unit* mUnit;
      int mRandomClass;
 };
```

Here's my Spawner.cpp file (Spawner.cpp):

```
#include "Spawner.h"



Spawner::Spawner()
{
}

Spawner::~Spawner()
{
    delete mUnit;
    mUnit = NULL;
}

void Spawner::spawn(Unit *& unit)
{
    mRandomClass = rand() % 3 + 1;

    unit = new Unit("Enemy", mRandomClass);
    mUnit = unit;
}
```

And finally here is my main.cpp:

```
#include "Unit.h"
#include "Spawner.h"

// Create player
Unit* createPlayer();

// Display Stats
void displayStats(Unit* unit);

// Play 1 round
void playRound(Unit*player, Unit* enemy);

// Simulate 1 attack (implement Higher agility gets to atttack first)
void combat(Unit* player, Unit* enemy);



void main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    Unit* player = createPlayer();
    Unit* enemy = NULL;

    Spawner *spawner = new Spawner();

    int round = 1;

    while (true) {
        cout << "Round " << round << endl;
        spawner->spawn(enemy);

        player->check(enemy);
        enemy->check(player);

        playRound(player, enemy);

        // if player is dead, end the game
        if (player->getHp() == 0) break;

        // else, add stats
        player->lvlUp();

        delete enemy;
        enemy = NULL;


        cout << "You defeted an enemy" << endl;
        system("pause>nul");
        system("cls");

        round++;
    }

    cout << "You were defeted! " << endl;
    cout << "You survived until Round " << round << endl;
    displayStats(player);

    delete player;
    player = NULL;
    delete spawner;
    spawner = NULL;
    system("pause>nul");
    system("cls");


}

Unit* createPlayer()
{
    Unit* unit = NULL;
    string name;
    int classChoice;

    cout << "Enter your Name: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    system("cls");

    cout << "Pick a class: " << endl
        << "\t [ 1 ] Warrior" << endl
        << "\t [ 2 ] Assassin" << endl
        << "\t [ 3 ] Mage" << endl
        << endl;
    cin >> classChoice;

    while (classChoice > 3 || classChoice <= 0) {
        cout << "INVALID INPUT! Please try again" << endl;
        cout << "Pick a class: " << endl
            << "\t [ 1 ] Warrior" << endl
            << "\t [ 2 ] Assassin" << endl
            << "\t [ 3 ] Mage" << endl
            << endl;
        cin >> classChoice;
    }

    unit = new Unit(name, classChoice);

    return unit;
}

void displayStats(Unit* unit)
{
    cout << "=========================================================================================" << endl
        << "Name: " << unit->getName() << " \t \t \t HP: " << unit->getHp() << " / " << unit->getMaxHp() << endl
        << "Class: " << unit->getClass() << endl
        << "==========================================================================================" << endl
        << "POW: " << unit->getPower() << endl
        << "VIT: " << unit->getVitality() << endl
        << "AGI: " << unit->getAgility() << endl
        << "DEX: " << unit->getDexterity() << endl
        << endl;
}


void playRound(Unit*player, Unit* enemy)
{
    while (player->getHp() > 0 && enemy->getHp() > 0) {
        displayStats(player);
        displayStats(enemy);
        system("pause>nul");

        combat(player, enemy);
        system("cls");
    }

}

void combat(Unit* player, Unit* enemy)
{
    if (player->getFirstToAttack()) {
        player->attack(enemy);
        if (player->getHit() == ATTACK_MISS) cout << player->getName() << "'s Attack Missed! " << endl;
        else if (player->getHit() == ATTACK_HIT) cout << player->getName() << " dealt " << player->getDamage() << " Damage" << endl;
        system("pause>nul");
        if (enemy->getHp() == 0) return;

        enemy->attack(player);
        if (enemy->getHit() == ATTACK_MISS) cout << enemy->getName() << "'s Attack Missed! " << endl;
        else if (enemy->getHit() == ATTACK_HIT) cout << enemy->getName() << " dealt " << enemy->getDamage() << " Damage" << endl;
        system("pause>nul");
        return;
    }


    else if (enemy->getFirstToAttack()) {
        enemy->attack(player);
        if (enemy->getHit() == ATTACK_MISS) cout << enemy->getName() << "'s Attack Missed! " << endl;
        else if (enemy->getHit() == ATTACK_HIT) cout << enemy->getName() << " dealt " << enemy->getDamage() << " Damage" << endl;
        system("pause>nul");
        if (player->getHp() == 0) return;

        player->attack(enemy);
        if (player->getHit() == ATTACK_MISS) cout << player->getName() << "'s Attack Missed! " << endl;
        else if (player->getHit() == ATTACK_HIT) cout << player->getName() << " dealt " << player->getDamage() << " Damage" << endl;
        system("pause>nul");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to ask questions like this in [Game Development Stack Exchange.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Give `round` to your spawner might help.

Comment: Please do not use `void main()` it's undefined behavior. Use one of the defined entry points, maybe `int main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "level" to the `Unit` class, and use the level to increase the stats of the unit (for example level 2 could mean the stats are multiplied by 1.5 or some such). Pass the `level` as an argument to the constructor similar to the units class.

Comment: How can i increment the level if i keep deallocating the enemy every end of the round

Comment: @Ken In your case the level can simply be equal to the round. The first round you have units of level one, the second round you have enemies of level 2, etc. So when you spawn an enemy simply pass the round, which is then passed as a level to the `Unit` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your spawner aware of how many enemies it has spawned:

```
// this belongs into your class definition, it should start at zero
int mCurrentSpawn;
```

So set it to zero in your constructor:

```
Spawner::Spawner()
{
   mCurrentSpawn = 0;
}
```

Then reference it when you spawn an enemy:

```
void Spawner::spawn(Unit *& unit)
{
    mRandomClass = rand() % 3 + 1;

    unit = new Unit("Enemy", mRandomClass);
    mUnit = unit;

    mCurrentSpawn++;

    int levelUps = mCurrentSpawn - 1;

    while(levelUps > 0)
    {
       mUnit->lvlUp(); 
       levelUps--;
    }
}
```

Comment: It only levels up depending on the opposing class

if you beat a Warrior:
HP +3
VIT+3

Assassin:
AGI+3
Dex+3

Mage
POW +5


since my Class is constant, his stats will not be balanced
for example, i am a Warrior, only his HP and Vit will grow

Comment: Also lvlup wont work because i recently deallocated the enemy, So all other functions are useless until you call the void Unit::check(Unit* target) function

Comment: I don't really understand your comments. If you want a different leveling process for your enemies, write one. This is just an example using the same leveling up as your player. It seems you did not really try it. Why would `lvlUp` not work before `check`? They don't seem connected. And shouldn't be.

Comment: because the unit will check  first his opponents class and then evaluates the stats bonus based on that class

Comment: To me it seems leveling first *and then* calling check seems to be the correct order.